# Specific API call doesn't work only in production server

Tags: php, api, curl

I've been for almost 2 months trying to debug and diagnose this issue to no avail. This is my last resort.
Long story short (short as possible):

In an application i've been developing  for a client(php/laravel), we are connecting to an external API (in china), to fetch data from cloud-connected monitoring devices.
The API calls are a bit complex in the sense that the headers need to be generated with a bunch of cryptic hashes that depend on the time and content of the request. No problem, everything was working fine.

Comes August 12, and out of the blues it fails, no longer fetches any data and gives no errors.
I had made some changes to the application code (although not that part), so I tested on my machine and in the staging server, all running the same code, and everything worked fine. It only fails in production.

We thought it might be connection issues or even a blacklisted IP, but those options have been discarded.

To make matters worse, I began to connect via command line curl (to make sure the application was not causing the issue) and the problem persists. Works everywhere except in production.
I then discovered that if I do a mal-formatted header (purposely miswrite the signature or whatever) the API responds with an error (as expected). So its for sure not a connection thing of any sort.
When the headers are well formed, the command works everywhere EXCEPT in production. No updates to any system libraries have been made.

I tried to diagnose curl via command line to see what kind of errors it was outputing. The result left me even more confused: there are no errors, no return codes, NOTHING. It just returns blank (zero bytes).

Here's a malformed request, which makes the API return a failure (as expected)

[image]

And here is a good request, returning 0 bytes (not expected):

[image]

I'm totally lost on what to do... ran out of ideas. The guys on the API side said they did their own diagnosis and found no issues.

What can I try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a malformed request, which makes the API return a failure (as expected) https://i.imgur.com/JMXfW5M.png
And here is a good request, returning 0 bytes (not expected): https://i.imgur.com/cdjbGj1.png

Comment: If it fails with `curl`, then it's not a problem in your code. It really sounds like the API is blocking you for some reason.

Comment: "We thought it might be connection issues or even a blacklisted IP, but those options have been discarded." How have you discarded them? Connectivity to China is subject to pretty significant potential restrictions and filtering. I wouldn't be at all surprised if they've blacklisted wide swaths of popular cloud providers' IP spaces.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to tell the API to add your production site to its "allowed hosts" list, so: which API, and what did you already check to confirm it's not simply a permissions issue (i.e. auth, host clearance, etc). Most "secure" APIs will not tell you what's wrong when you mess up auth of any form, so as not to give hackers any clues as to what they can change to get incrementally closer to access, and "an error" is all you'll get. The API docs and the company's support team are there for you to figure out what you're doing wrong, instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz I discarded because it connects successfully (and outputs an error) when the header is malformed. So it cant be a connection thing

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the guys in china say that is not a problem. And it was working until 12 August, so it doesnt seem to be a permission issue.

Comment: If it worked until a certain date, but not after the issue is server-side.

Comment: @Evert that's my guess as well, but the guys there seem reluctant to continue any sort of investigation. From their perspective, if the same code works in other computers, the problem is on our server...

Comment: It sounds like you have more of a people problem than a technical problem. Get them on a call and figure out a way where you can work together rather than as adversaries.

Comment: What Evert said. This is effectively an off-topic problem that Stackoverflow cannot help with: this is a workplace problem.